# Looking for a string in two iterators in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

In C++, I am aware that you can have multiple iterators. For example, if you had a function that wanted to see the first concurrence of a string in two iterators why would a code look something like this:

```
Iterator found_it(Iterator one, Iterator two){
while(one != two && (*one) != "Bob"){
    one++;
}
return one;
}
```

***The question said one and two don't necessarily mean begin() and end() - that is what really gave me a mind**** and confusion :S***

Firstly, what happens if `Bob` was in iterator `two`? Because you are only returning iterator `one`? This is what is really confusing me at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get this code, what do you think it is intended to do, and why do you trust it?

Comment: In your example, iterator `two` is the iterator to the element AFTER last element you want to search. So it doesn't even have to point anything. It is often, for instance `std::vector.end()`.

Comment: If "Bob" is in iterator two then it is out of the range you wish to search so it should not be found. The second iterator is *one past* the search range. So you search from `one` up to, but not including, `two`.

Comment: For terminology, "Bob" isn't in iterator two. Iterator two points at "Bob".

Answer (score 1):

When two iterators used as a range for a function or a standard algorithm then the second iterator is not included in the range. That is you should consider the range like

```
[first, last )
```

If a function or algorithm like `std::find` returns the second iterator then it means that the range does not contain the target value.

If the second iterator was included in the range then a question arises  what iterator to return when the target value is not found?

Consider for example your own function with the following its calls

```
template <class Iterator>
Iterator found_it(Iterator one, Iterator two){
while(one != two && (*one) != "Bob"){
    one++;
}
return one;
}

//...

std::vector<std::string> v1 = { "Mary", "Bob" };
std::vector<std::string> v2 = { "Mary", "Peter" };

auto it1 = found_it( v1.begin(), v1.end() );

if ( it1 != v1.end() ) std::cout << *it1 << " is present in v1" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "Bob" << " is not present in v1" << std::endl;

auto it2 = found_it( v2.begin(), v2.end() );

if ( it2 != v2.end() ) std::cout << *it2 << " is present in v2" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "Bob" << " is not present in v2" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If "Bob" is at iterator two then it is out of the range you wish to search so it should not be found. The second iterator is *one past* the search range.

So you search from `one` up to, but not including, `two`.

When you want to search an *entire container* then you will pass `begin()` and `end()` as arguments to `one` and `two`. But iterators give you the flexibility to search for intermediate ranges within a *container*.

For example what if you want to find *all the Bobs*?

```
std::vector<std::string> names {"Tim", "Beryl", "Bob", "Danny", "Bob", "Lou"};
```

You can get the first one like this:

```
auto bob1 = fond_it(names.begin(), names.end());
```

You can get the second one like this:

```
auto bob2 = fond_it(bob1 + 1, names.end());
```

Notice you can start the search half way through using `bob1` rather than at the beginning.

Comment: Further, some iterators don't deal with containers at all. For example, `std::istream_iterator`.

Comment: I see! I get it now I think. So basically if I am every asked a question to find an element in the range(x,y) where `x` and `y` are iterators this implies that `x` is equivalent to say `container.begin()` and `y` is equivalent to `container.end()+1` - i.e out of scope? Are iterators (multiple iterators) in particular used for multiple containers?

Comment: @SamuelKielsfierou Well `container.end()` is *already* out of scope because `container.end()` points **outside** the container (by one position). Your *algorithm* in `find_it()` searches every element of the *container* that the *iterators* point to from the element pointed to by `one` up to, but **not** including the element pointed to by `two`.

Answer (score 0):

`one` and `two` are the beginning and end (really just beyond the end) of the range that you want to search. This might not be the same as `begin()` and `end()` on a container, if you wanted to search only a subrange, or if the iterators don't come from a container at all.

Note that `one` is changed within the loop; you're not necessarily returning the original value of `one`.

Your function could be rewritten equivalently like this:

```
Iterator found_it(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
  Iterator current = begin;
  while (current != end && (*current) != "Bob"){
    current++;
  }
  return current;
}
```

Comment: I see, this is making sense. So if the value `Bob` was found - what would be returned?